# subprocess bash script doesn't modify environment variables globally

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a bash script that assigns several environment variables. As a simpler example, we may have something like

```sh
export A=a
```

This script is called `exporter.sh`.

I'm trying to run this script from python by using `subprocess.run`. The following python script runs the exporter script and checks that the environment variables have been set correctly:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("bash exporter.sh", shell=True)

print(subprocess.run(
    "echo $A",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

This, however, doesn't return anything. How can I set bash environment variables globally in python?

Comment: Do you need the bash script to set the environment variables? Could you set these environment variables directly from your Python code?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my main requirement, I'm re-using a bash script from that is in my code-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `subprocess.run` gets its own (new) shell. In your original code:

1. `subprocess.run` opens a `sh` shell (default for `subprocess`).
2. `sh` opens a `bash` shell and sets the variable (within the `bash` shell).
3. Both `bash` and `sh` shells are closed (because your first `subprocess.run` command is finished) and the newly set env. variables are destroyed.
4. `echo $A` is launched in a new `sh` shell, which doesn't know that a previous shell had the variables.

You could run 'setter' and 'getter' together in the same bash shell.

**exporter.sh**:

```
export A=b_set_from_exporter.sh
```

**python script**:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "bash -c 'source ./exporter.sh && echo $A'"
print(subprocess.run(
    cmd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Out**:

```
b_set_from_exporter.sh
```

**Note:**

If you really need to set variables globally and accessible (and forever) to be shared over multiple bash shells, set them in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't allow for environment variables set in the called bash script to be accessible from python. This just allows environment variables to be exposed to the called bash script.

Comment: Is there any function that doesn't have the restriction to have its own shell?

Comment: @David Masip: Edited.